# Spawn multiple aws sync instances from a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, aws

Im trying to have my bash script simply run a bunch of `aws s3 sync` commands at the same time and not do them one by one. It appears that it is only doing one of them at a time instead of doing them all at once. My config is setup so I can run 10+ `aws s3 sync` at a time. If I ran all the `aws` commands manually, they will all run and start their uploads. Im not sure why this isn't working...

```
#!/bin/bash
aws s3 sync /usr/local/backup1/latestbackup/ s3://abucket/backup1/
aws s3 sync /usr/local/backup2/latestbackup/ s3://abucket/backup2/
aws s3 sync /usr/local/backup3/latestbackup/ s3://abucket/backup3/
```

Why is it not spawning them all at once?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Answer (score 1):

Oops! I was able to fix this by just adding `&` at the end of each of the lines.